# Set-Secret failing with Hashtable

Tags: powershell

Try to call Powershell SecretManagement Set-Secret with a Hashtable as documented [here](https://Set-Secret:%20Exception%20calling)

```
$jsonHt = @{ foo = 42 }                            
Set-Secret -Vault LocalStore -Name MySecret -Secret $jsonHt
```

Returns:

> Set-Secret: Exception calling "WriteObject" with "4" argument(s): "The
> object type for foo Hashtable entry is not supported. Supported types
> are byte[], string, SecureString, PSCredential"

Is there anything wrong with my code or expectations?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anything wrong with my code or expectations?

As the error implies, you need to *serialize* your data somehow, so that it may fit into a string or a byte array.

Converting the data structure to JSON and storing that would be my suggestion:

```
$jsonHt = @{ foo = 42 }                            
Set-Secret -Vault LocalStore -Name MySecret -Secret ($jsonHt |ConvertTo-Json)
```

Then you just need to remember to call `ConvertFrom-Json` when retrieving the secret:

```
$secretHT = Get-Secret -Secret -Vault LocalStore -Name MySecret -AsPlainText |ConvertFrom-Json
```

Comment: I think the important part is the link I sent, which from MS doc says: Specifies the value of the secret. The object must be one of the supported types:

    Byte[]
    String
    SecureString
    PSCredential
    **Hashtable**

Comment: @AlainP You haven't linked to any documentation, but the error message only states "byte[], string, SecureString, PSCredential"

Comment: Well it appears that the link in my question wasn't captured properly. Here it is verbatim: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.secretmanagement/set-secret?view=ps-modules#-secret

Comment: @AlainP What backend vault are you using? Perhaps it doesn't support hashtables

Comment: I'm using MS PowerShell SecretStore and in the how to for it (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/utility-modules/secretmanagement/get-started/using-secretstore?view=ps-modules) they list Hashtable as an option. Can't find other specific confirmation